# HTML value within JSON being truncated when received via ajax in ie

Tags: ajax, json, internet-explorer

Weird sentence.. weird issue.

I have some json like this:

```
  {
     "id":"1246",
     "cost":"62.1603017827",
     "material":"Blue",
     "class":"veroblue",
     "label":" ($62.16)",
     "mlabel":"Blue",
     "html":"<div class=\"quote\">\r\n\t<input type=radio name=\"QuoteUploads[selectedMaterial]\" value=\"1246\" checked=checked id=\"quote_uploads_quote_1246\" data-color=\"#A9BCF5\"\/>\r\n\t<label for=\"quote_uploads_quote_1246\" ><span class=\"swatch veroblue\"><span class=\"big veroblue\"><\/span> <\/span><span class=\"text\">Blue <span class=\"cost\">($62.16)<\/span><\/span><\/label>\r\n<\/div>\t"
  },
```

When my page loads the above is already in an object qobj. When I console.log(qobj.html) I get:

```
<div class="quote">
  <input type=radio name="QuoteUploads[selectedMaterial]" value="1250"  id="quote_uploads_quote_1250" data-color="#FBF8EF"/>
  <label for="quote_uploads_quote_1250" ><span class="swatch duruswhite"><span class="big duruswhite"></span> </span><span class="text">Polypropylene-Like <span class="cost">($62.21)</span></span></label>
</div>
```

Now, when an input changes I reload the JSON via AJAX and store it in qobj. After it is reloaded console.log(qobj.html) outputs:

```
    </span> </span>Polypropylene-Like ($62.21)</span></span></label>
</div>
```

The json string is encoded and rendered the same way when it is injected and received via ajax. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Check the string that is before the </span> after reloading the JSON. Most probably is a double quotes somewhere cutting the console log. Other thing to try is load in console log each property: id, cost, material and so on. On one you will find something odd.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing any of your code.

Comment: the text is in the http response, and I don't really have a good code example to show. The json is rendered in php using json_encode(array(... "html"=>include("file"))